# how to add a row to an existing Google spreadsheet with Google Drive API for PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I've already tried the sample application from the tutorial, but how can I add a row to an existing spreadsheet file from my php page?

What do I have to pass to the [update function](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) ???

What I want to accomplish is to insert a new row with some data after each form submit

Comment: did you tried and get any solution with Spreadsheets API ?

Comment: No, we went on by using a differente solution using a plain old html form, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong api. You need the spreadsheet api at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ , not the Drive api

Answer (score 1):

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('GoogleSheets');
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/credentials.json');

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
/**
* Write Row Google Sheet
*/
    
$spreadsheetID = '------';
$range = 'Sheet1';//Correct here for your sheet name
$values = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
];
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
    'values' => $values
]);
$params = [
    'valueInputOption' => 'RAW',
];
$insert = [
    "insertDataOption"=> "INSERT_ROWS",
];
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetID, $range, $body, $params, $insert);
```